# Bulk-edit HelpContext and/or HelpKeyword of project files?

Tags: delphi, delphi-2009, helpfile, helpcontext

currently I'm editing the HelpContext and/or HelpKeyword properties of the appropriate controls one after another in my D2009 project forms, where applicable.

Is there any tool which can collect all those mentioned properties from all project files, list them in a read-able manner, in a table or similar (including the form's and the controls's name and probably more), for easy modification?

Thanks,
Michael

Comment: We never found anything to do this automatically, but it's not hard to make a utility in delphi that reads DFM's and puts helpcontexts and component names in a listview.